# AssetManager долго грузит звук

Tags: java, libgdx

Пытаюсь загрузить 'bang.ogg' из папки assets с помощью AssetManager:

```
am.load("bang.ogg", Sound.class);
am.finishLoading();
```

После сборки получаю apk на 2Мб. Устанавливаю на свой Xiaomi Redmi 4X и жду целых 2 минуты, пока загрузится файлик на 42Кб.

Приложение тестовое, гружу только эту мелодию. Загрузка файлов других типов (картинки, модели и т.п.) так сильно не тормозит. При этом точно известно, что проблема именно в этих 2 строках, то есть в загрузке.

В чём проблема? Как исправить?

Comment: Т.е. кроме этого одного файла вы больше ничего не грузите? Что если поробовать загрузить без AssetManager'а?

Comment: Ничего не гружу. Без AssetManager'а вылетает (file not loaded), это из-за андроида. С другой музыкой в ogg формате то же самое.

Comment: Очень странно. Поробуйте загрузить так Sound sound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("bang.ogg"));

Comment: БЕЗ ASSETMANGER'A ВЫЛЕТАЕТ (ASSET NOT LOADED): https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/2860

Comment: Refresh'ить пробовал, иначе ассеты вообще не грузились.

Answer (score 0):

Всё заработало само собой, без каких-либо изменений. Наверное баг в android.

***Программирование - страна чудес***